# How can I estimate MIN and MAX (table1 package)

Tags: r, html-table

table1 package function defaults to reporting Median and SD (see screenshot), however, I would like to get MIN and MAX as well. Using the example below how can I get the MIN and MAX along with Median and SD?

```
library(boot) 
library(table1)

melanoma2 <- melanoma
 
# Factor the basic variables that
# we're interested in
melanoma2$status <- 
  factor(melanoma2$status, 
         levels=c(2,1,3),
         labels=c("Alive", # Reference
                  "Melanoma death", 
                  "Non-melanoma death"))

table1(~ factor(sex) + age + factor(ulcer) + thickness | status, data=melanoma2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this output the format you are looking for?

```r
library(boot) 
library(table1)

melanoma2 <- melanoma
 
# Factor the basic variables that
# we're interested in
melanoma2$status <- 
  factor(melanoma2$status, 
         levels=c(2,1,3),
         labels=c("Alive", # Reference
                  "Melanoma death", 
                  "Non-melanoma death"))

table1(~ factor(sex) + age + factor(ulcer) + thickness | status, render.continuous=c(.="Min", .="Max", .="Median", .="SD"), data=melanoma2)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Another statistic to report came to mind. Is there a way to add confidence intervals for each category as well or to the Overall column?